# I have something error in my project

Tags: build

how to fix this error..??

Errormessage:

Program type already present: com.android.volley.Cache$Entry
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.android.volley.Cache$Entry, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just remove

`implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`

and add

`implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'`

in your code and build it gives correct :)